# Pyodbc to Hive on Dataproc intermittent error: (79) Failed to reconnect to server. (79) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: hive, connection, odbc, pyodbc, google-cloud-dataproc

I launch a Dataproc cluster with Hive using GoogleAPIs in Python and connect to the Hive with `pyodbc`. Hive queries succeed and fail seemingly randomly.

`Cloudera` Hive ODBC driver 2.6.9

`pyodbc` 4.0.30

Error: `"pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Cloudera][Hardy] (79) Failed to reconnect to server. (79) (SQLExecDirectW)')"`

Some server logs:

```
{
"insertId": "xxx",
"jsonPayload": {
"filename": "yarn-yarn-timelineserver-xxx-m.log",
"class": "org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager",
"message": "ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted"
},
```

```
{
"insertId": "xxx",
"jsonPayload": {
"container": "container_xxx_0002_01_000001",
"thread": "ORC_GET_SPLITS #4",
"application": "application_xxx_0002",
"message": "Failed to get files with ID; using regular API: Only supported for DFS; got class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem",
"class": "|io.AcidUtils|",
"filename": "application_xxx_0002.container_xxx_0002_01_000001.syslog_dag_xxx_0002_4",
"container_logname": "syslog_dag_xxx_0002_4"
},
```